# Modules of algebraic integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers, field-theory, integers

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ be an algebraic integer. Is then $|z| \in \mathbb{R}$ also an algebraic integer?

Comment: Yes. $\bar z$ is an algebraic integer since it shares the same minimal polynomial as $z$. So $|z| = \sqrt{z\bar z}$ is also an algebraic integer.

Comment: @HwChu Why didn't you post that as an answer? Because that's what it is.

Answer (score 2):

With $z$ also $\overline{z}$ is an algebraic integer, because it is a root of the same minimal polynomial. Since the algebraic integers form a ring, also the product $z\cdot\overline{z}$ is an algebraic integer. Then also its square root, i.e., $|z|=\sqrt{z\overline{z}}$.